# Display other form elements based on radio selection

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to display a specific block of html with some form elements based on whatever is selected in a radio button.

Below is the framework of what I have, I didn't include any of the JQUERY that I tried because I couldn't get anything to work. Any chance someone could help me fill in the blanks?

TIA!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.chainedSelects.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    showValBox = function(data) {

    };  
});
</script>


<form action="" method="post" id="SomeForm" />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-ctr">Size</td>
        <td class="td-ct"><input type="radio" name="Radio" value="Value1" onChange="showValBox(this.value)" /> Value <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="Value2" onChange="showValBox(this.value)" /> Value</td>
    </tr>
    <div id="Value1" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td class="td-ctr">Only if Value 1</td>
        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    </div>          
    <div id="Value2" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="td-ct">Online if Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName1</td>
        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName1" value="" /></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName2</td>
        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName2" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName3</td>
        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName3" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName4/td>
        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName4" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName5</td>
        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName5" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName6</td>
        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName6" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName7</td>
        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName7" value="" /></td>
    </tr>                                                                               
    </div>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, you cannot semantically have DIV's between your table rows.  They must be contained within your TD elements.  I would suggest you *apply your ID tag to the TR element* which will hide the entire row. Second, I would suggest all of your TR's share a class to easily hide elements when the radio changes.

1. hidden rows share the class **hiddenContainers**

**CODE**

```
$(ready(function() {
    $("input[name='Radio']").click(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('.hiddenContainers').hide();
        $('#'+val).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe IE doesn't handle well change event, you should probably use click instead.

Comment: I tried this also using tbody (cause another post says tr's don't work with ie) and again I got nothing, everything appears on the page and nothing goes away when the radio is selected

Comment: *"The .hide() and .show() methods, without animation, are always safe to use with table rows."*

Comment: Ahh, thanks cballou - this is getting me closer. it does switch when I change the radio, but it only does 1 tr, not all of them. I guess I could put it in a nested table.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML isn't valid because the DIV elements need to be inside a column if you include them in a table.  What you really want to do is give your rows different classes depending on which set they belong to and then show/hide based on the class.  You might consider using a "hidden" class to control the "display: none;" style, then simply add/remove this class.

I would probably run it on click and use jQuery:

```
$('[name=Radio]').click( function() {
   var klass = '.' + $(this).val();
   $('.class1,.class2').addClass('hidden');
   $(klass).removeClass('hidden');
});

<form action="" method="post" id="SomeForm" />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-ctr">Size</td>
        <td class="td-ct">
            <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="class1" /> Value
            <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="class2"  /> Value
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="class1 hidden">
        <td class="td-ctr">Only if Value 1</td>
        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="class2 hidden">
        <td colspan="2" class="td-ct">Online if Value 2</td>
    </tr
    ...
```

Comment: IIRC, you need to hide the cells as opposed to the row to get this to play nicely in IE

Comment: This looked good, so I gave it a try using tbody instead of the tr, but it didn't work - all of it appears by default and nothing is hidden when I change the radio selection.

Comment: Did you set up the "hidden" style class to have "display: none;"  If you used this technique, that is critical.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but a comment on the two other answers already present that are noting you cannot put DIVs in between your rows...

For this purpose, i.e., grouping related rows into a single element, you might be interested in the TBODY element,

```
<table>
    <tbody id="somegroup">
        <tr><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="someOthergroup">
        <tr><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really use the change events on the actual tags so that the code will gracefully degrade allowing both options to be visible. This code will also remember which radio is selected when the page is refreshed and display the correct section.

You cannot put a DIV tag in the middle of a TABLE like that either so I re-factored the code a bit for you.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("tbody[id^='Value']").hide();
                $("input[name='Radio']").click(function(){
                    change_selection();
                });
                change_selection();
            });

            function change_selection() {
                var selected_value = $("input[name='Radio']:checked").val();
                $("tbody[id^='Value']").hide();
                $("#" + selected_value).show();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" id="SomeForm" />
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-ctr">Size</td>
                        <td class="td-ct"><input type="radio" name="Radio" value="Value1" checked="checked"/> Value <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="Value2" /> Value</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody id="Value1">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-ctr">Only if Value 1</td>
                        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody id="Value2">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="td-ct">Only if Value 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName1</td>
                        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName1" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>       
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName2</td>
                        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName2" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName3</td>
                        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName3" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName4</td>
                        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName4" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName5</td>
                        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName5" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName6</td>
                        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName6" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-ctr">SomeName7</td>
                        <td class="td-ct"><input type="text" name="SomeName7" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>                                                                                                                                                               
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Cheers,
Dean

Comment: I tried this exactly as is and it didn't work, nothing would change when I changed the radio button - would it matter if I had other radio buttons in the form?

Comment: It should work with other radio buttons as it is only targeting inputs with a name of "Radio", just make sure none of your other inputs have the same name. It would be worth copying the code I supplied to a single HTML file and giving it a test and a play first to make sure you understand how it is all working.

Cheers,
Dean